# Magento 2.4.6 and Bootstrap : jQuery Version

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, magento2

I have an install of Magento CE 2.4.6 with a third party template.
When loading pages I have the following errors in console :

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3
<anonymous> http://xxx/static/frontend/Ortho/tizzyWatch/fr_FR/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js:6
<anonymous> http://xxx/static/frontend/Ortho/tizzyWatch/fr_FR/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js:6
```

When in console i do :

```
jQuery.fn.jquery
"3.6.0"
```

I found in my theme a readmefile saying : Bootstrap version 3.3.6 on 27th april included

What may I do to clear these jQuery issues?

- Updating to Bootstrap 4 or 5? How ?
- Force to use jQuery version under 3.0 ? How ?

### Thank you for your help,